# How to parse a large HTML file with Java HTMLParser library

Tags: java, parsing

I have some html files created by Filemaker export. Each file is basically a huge HTML table. I want to iterate through the table rows and populate them into a database. I have tried to do it with [HTMLParser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/) as follows:

```
String inputHTML = readFile("filemakerExport.htm","UTF-8");
Parser parser = new Parser();
parser.setInputHTML(inputHTML);
parser.setEncoding("UTF-8");    
NodeList nl = parser.parse(null); 
NodeList trs = nl.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("tr"),true);
for(int i=0;i<trs.size();i++) {
    NodeList nodes = trs.elementAt(i).getChildren();
    NodeList tds  = nodes.extractAllNodesThatMatch(new TagNameFilter("td"),true);
    // Do stuff with tds
}
```

The above code works with files under 1 Mb. Unfortunately I have a 4.8 Mbs html file and I get an out of memory error.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at org.htmlparser.lexer.Lexer.parseTag(Lexer.java:1002)
    at org.htmlparser.lexer.Lexer.nextNode(Lexer.java:369)
    at org.htmlparser.scanners.CompositeTagScanner.scan(CompositeTagScanner.java:111)
    at org.htmlparser.util.IteratorImpl.nextNode(IteratorImpl.java:92)
    at org.htmlparser.Parser.parse(Parser.java:701)
    at Tools.main(Tools.java:33)
```

Is there a more efficient way to solve this problem with HTMLParser (I am totally new to the library), or should I use a different library or approach?

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried increased the max heap size of the JVM

The following command line argument will up it to 512 megabytes:
-Xmx512M

E.g.

```
java -Xmx512M myrunclass
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. I up vote you. I will wait to accept your answer because I want to see if someone posts a more efficinet way.

Comment: Sergio del Amo, I think you should accept this answer as there was no other questions that you liked.

Answer (score 1):

Don't build a DOM when you only want to extract some information and you are not interested to perform some XPath queries or other type of queries which perform best on a DOM structure(parent-child relations, etc).

Use Parser.visitAllNodesWith() instead of Prser.parse().

Comment: Have a look in org.htmlparser.tests.visitorsTests package, you'll find all test cases related with visitors. Everyting you need to know about parsing with a visitor is there.

You have an implementation close to what you need : TagFindingVisitor. 

TagFindingVisitor visitor =
            new TagFindingVisitor(
                new String [] {
                    "LI","BODY","UL","A"
                }
            );
        parser.visitAllNodesWith(visitor);

Answer (score 1):

I've faced the same problem. It seems HtmlParser suffers from memory leaks problems and lack of documentation. Doing profiling with JProfiler I've noticed that parsing pages HtmlParser holds link to html code it processed. I've try calling parser.reset() at the end of parsing. It doesn't help. I've also looked on testing code, but found no hints.

As a result I've dramatically decreased memory usage by calling parser.setInputHTML(""); when I don't need parser object more.

P.S. it's better to analyse HtmlParser's source code, but I don't have time for this :)

Answer (score 0):

HTMLParser has both a parser and a lexer. The parser builds an in memory model but the lexer just notifies you of the tags in the file. For a simple extraction of fixed data then the lexer may be the most efficient way of extracting the data with you having to track the structure of the html as the tags are encountered. The HTMlParser library has not had a release for a while so memory issues are worrying as they seem unlikely to get fixed. Try JSoup if you need a high level parse as that has a powerful query syntax and is very easy to use.